# Android: Is there any other way to get the SIM number from the android device other than getLine1number()?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I tried getLine1number(), for some device it gets the number. but for some, it returns empty string("").
As far as I tested, when in the device's Settings > Status > My Phone number is not empty, I get the number otherwise I am not able to get the Phone number.

Is there any other way to get the Phone number other than the above method?

Comment: Settings app uses the same method. For an alternative, you can ask the user.

Comment: Yeah, you are right laalto but i am trying some how to get the number myself, so it would be appreciated if you can suggest any other way to get the number. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge their is no any way to find a telephone number other than **.getLine1Number()** method.

**Provide you some options that you try:-**

**A)** If number return null means, your phone number not register in your mobile.For that you can use the sim card serial number.It is unique number.

```
 TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
```

**B)** The method you are using is the only one part of the SDK to do this, 
and only works on devices where the number is stored on the SIM card, 
which only some carriers do. For all other carriers, 
you will have to ask the user to enter the phone number manually, 
as the number is simply not stored anywhere on the device from where you can retrieve it.

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but still disappointed that there is no other way to get the number. Anyway once again thanks for your answer.